# ¿Cómo manejar varios componentes hijo en ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Mi pregunta es sencilla:
¿Cómo puedo manejar el valor de dos componentes hijo?
Ejemplo:

Tengo esta clase, Board:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Square from './Square';

    export default class Board extends Component {
    
        render(){
            return (
                <>
                    <Square />
                    <Square />
                </>
            );
        }
    
    }
```

y este es el componente hijo:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Square = (props) => {

    let initStatusMessage = 'Aún no se ha clicado.'
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(initStatusMessage);

    function handleClick(){
        setCount(count + 1);
        if(status === initStatusMessage){
            setStatus('Veces clicado: ');
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <p>{status}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>{count}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Square;
```

¿De que manera, en lugar de manejar el valor del count por cada uno de los hijos, puedo manejar los diferentes valores desde el padre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El componente padre puede llevar el control independiente de cada uno de sus hijos, por ejemplo a través de un state en el padre y una función que tus hijos reciben como "callback" para actualizar el state en el padre.

Algo así:

```js
const Square = (props) => {
    const { count, onChange } = props;
    let initStatusMessage = 'Aún no se ha clicado.'
    const [status, setStatus] = React.useState(initStatusMessage);

    function handleClick(){
        onChange(count + 1);
        if(count > 0){
            setStatus('Veces clicado: ');
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <p>{status}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>{count}</button>
        </div>
    );
}


class Board extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
        childrenCounter: [0, 0]
      }
    }

    handleChange = (index, value) => {
      const nextCounter = [...this.state.childrenCounter];
      nextCounter[index] = value
      this.setState({
        childrenCounter: nextCounter,
      })
    }

    render() {
      const { childrenCounter } = this.state;
      
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Square count={childrenCounter[0]} onChange={(val) => this.handleChange(0, val)} />
                <Square count={childrenCounter[1]} onChange={(val) => this.handleChange(1, val)} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias !!! lo he modificado un poco yo a mi manera, pero es lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas un componente funcional (no se como se haria con clases) puedes poner el estado y el manejador de click en el padre y pasarselo como props a los hijos, de esta manera (lo hice en una pc que no tiene react como para probar, puede haber algo mal, tu pruebalo y cualquier cosa me dices):

```
import Square from './Square';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

    export default  const Board = () => {

  let initStatusMessage = 'Aún no se ha clicado.'
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(initStatusMessage);

    function handleClick(){
        setCount(count + 1);
        if(status === initStatusMessage){
            setStatus('Veces clicado: ');
        }
    }
    
        render(){
            return (
                <>
                    <Square count={count} status={status} handleClick={handleClick} />
                    <Square count={count} status={status} handleClick={handleClick} />
                </>
            );
        }
    
    }
```

el componete square:

```
const Square = (props) => {

    return(
        <div>
            <p>{props.status}</p>
            <button onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.count}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Square;
```

te recomiendo este curso, es muy bueno:
**https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvq-jIkSeTUZ5XcUw8fJPTBKEHEKPMTKk**

Comment: Entiendo lo que me comentas, graias por la atención prestada, pero me temo que tu ejemplo no me sirve.... ya que el valor de count sería el mismo en ambos, y quiero manejar cada count desde el padre independientemente en cada hijo. No sé si es posible o necesario hacerlo así.

Comment: No se bien el uso q le das. Intui q count contaba las veces q dieras click en ambos componentes. Puedes entonces generar un estado para cada componente

Comment: Un estado para cada uno? Dentro de cada componente un estado? O en el padre dos variables diferentes?